# Finishing Induction with Generalized PMI and Inequalities Proof

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, summation, induction, proof-explanation

I am kind of at a loss at how to approach this one as it has an inequality. I have this much thus far and I'm not sure how to continue. I have a picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, at the inductive step: $\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}1/i= \frac{1}{n+1} \prod_{i=1}^{n}1/i\leq \frac{1}{n+1}2^{-n}\leq 2^{-(n+1)}$, for every integer $n$.

Comment: i don't understand how you got the 1/1+n by itself

Comment: nvm I get it but I have trouble getting 1/n+1 times 2^-n to equal 2^-(n+1)

Comment: They are not equal, $\tfrac{2^{-n}}{n+1}\leq 2^{-(n+1)}%$ since $\tfrac{1}{n+1}\leq 2^{-1}\Leftrightarrow n+1\geq 2%$